# Unable to execute shell script using deploy command in jboss

Tags: linux, shell, unix, jboss

I have been looking for solutions to this problem for a couple of days and have not found a suitable one.

Currently i have two lines of code in my shell script file.

```
cd /app/jboss/sample_project/bin

./jboss-cli.sh  -c --controller=$hostnameVal:$jboss_port_no1 --user=$jboss_id --password=$jboss_pwd --command="deploy --force /sample/uploaded/sample-1.0.war --runtime-name=sample-1.0.war"
```

I am facing this error:

> '--force' is assumed to be a command(s) but the commands to execute have been specified by another argument: [deploy]

I think it has something to do with the spaces between deploy and --force but I can't seem to find a solution to this. Would really appreciate if someone can shed some light. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to escape the whitespaces with a backslash?

Comment: I have tried doing that, but maybe I am not doing it correctly. It would be very kind if you to provide me the correct syntax. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the issue was due to the space between the deploy command and the file path, therefore jboss was not be able to find the parameter the properly.

Hence, a work around for this which I have found out is to create a cli file, write the deploy command in the cli file and pass the file as an input in the script that i am writing.

Comment: Should be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you observe the same problem in a terminal?

Comment: Nope, this exact same command works perfectly fine in the terminal.

Comment: Can we see your script? I suspect a double quote issue, the syntax is valid.